# How to create a KTable specifying a json serializer and a store name with its Materialized definition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to create a KTable with an associated state store that can be queriable with interactive queries, for instance:

```
val builder = StreamsBuilder()
        builder.table(CUSTOMERS_TOPIC, Materialized.`as`<String, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>(CUSTOMERS_STORE))
```

However in order to serialize my Customer value class I need to specify a Json Serializer. I could do it using this method from StreamsBuilder:

```
public synchronized <K, V> KTable<K, V> table(final String topic,
                                                  final Consumed<K, V> consumed) {
```

with this Consumed:

`Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(JsonPojoSerializer<Customer>(), JsonPojoDeserializer(Customer::class.java)`

But as you see there is no way to set the store name. Moreover, according to the javadoc, the internal state store may not be queriable:

> with an internal store name. Note that store name may not be queriable
>   through Interactive Queries

So how can I configure the materialization with an specified name and also indicating the necessary Json serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scala API, Serdes are resolved via implicits. That's why there is no overload to pass in `Consumed` parameter. Cf. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/streams-scala/src/main/scala/org/apache/kafka/streams/scala/StreamsBuilder.scala#L88-L129

For Java, there is a method overload that allows you to pass in both parameters:

```java
public synchronized <K, V> KTable<K, V> table(final String topic,
                                              final Consumed<K, V> consumed,
                                              final Materialized<K, V, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized) {
```

Cf. https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#table-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-